# CommandName="Delete" doesn't call any method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-controls

I've got a Repeater-controller that looks something like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Postrepeater" runat="server" DataSourceID="datasource" >
<h2>
    <%#Eval("posttitle") %>
</h2>
<p>
    <%#Eval("posttext") %>
</p>
<asp:Button ID="DeleteLinkButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete post" />
</asp:Repeater>
```

The Datasource:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="datasource" TypeName="Service" SelectMethod="GetPosts" DataObjectTypeName="Post" runat="server" DeleteMethod="DeletePost" />
```

And in Service.cs

```
public List<Posts> GetPosts()
        {
            DALposts dal = new DALposts();
            return dal.GetPosts();
        }

public void DeletePost(Posts post)
    {
        DALPost.DeletePost(post.PostId);
    }
```

The really wierd thing is that the SelectMethod, GetPosts, works as a charm - just as it should. But when I try to delete the post, the DeleteMethod doesn't call any method - the page just reloads and nothing happens. I've tried to debug the code, but the CommandName="Delete" doesn't call anything at all, and I don't recieve any errors... Any ideas?

Think I posted enough code, but if you think you need more - just tell me so.

**Update:**
After lots of reading and some help here too, I came to the conclusion that this can't be done with a repeater unless I write quite a lot more code - so I canged to a FormView instead. Works like a charm

Comment: I think you need to assign the `OnClick` of `<asp:Button>` in order to have it do something.

Comment: Nope - You are supposed to be able to use the "commandName=" to tell the datasource what method to use. I've done this before, just can't understand why it doesn't work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think that it will be possible the way you have described it here with a repeater. You have to use an gridview instead.

Or you can use the OnItemCommand event on the repeater, check for the Delete argument and then call your delete method.

Comment: Yes, I changed to a FormView instead - was much easier to implement.

Answer (score 1):

To get something done by setting `CommandName` u have to implement `OnItemCommand` 
[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700284/delete-in-repeater)